# Value returned by read-host when CANCEL button is pressed

Tags: function, powershell, return, exit

According to this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0d8b981e-7757-4e72-a6f3-3eaa984d977e/what-is-the-value-returned-by-readhost-when-the-cancel-button-is-pressed?forum=winserverpowershell), the value that read-host returns when `CANCEL` button is pressed is `$NULL`

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $a = read-host "please cancel me"

____________________________________________________________________________
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> if ($A -eq $null) {'null'}
null
```

I have a function that prompts users for multiple pairs of passwords, and if the user presses `CANCEL` the function should exit

```
    if (($password -eq $NULL) -or ($confirmpassword -eq $NULL)){
        return
    }
```

Unfortunately, the script exits (because `"hello world"` is never printed)

```
function createPwdFiles(){


    $stamp = $(get-date -f HH_mm_ss) 

    $password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString

    $confirmpassword = Read-Host "Confirm password" -AsSecureString


    if (($password -eq $NULL) -or ($confirmpassword -eq $NULL)){
        return
    }

    $pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
    $pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($confirmpassword))
    if($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text) {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”) | Out-Null
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(“Passwords don't match, please try again”, “Passwords don't match”, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information) | Out-Null

    } 
    else{
        $password | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $pwd_path\$stamp.txt
        Add-Content $cred_path\pwd_list.txt $pwd_path\$stamp.txt
    }

}

$intAnswer = 6
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
do{
    createPwdFiles
    $intAnswer = $a.popup("Do you want add another password?", ` 0,"Password",4) 

}while ($intAnswer -eq 6) 


write-output "hello world"
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a $null check try using the System String class' IsNullOrEmpty static method.

```
$a = $null
$b = ""
[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($a)
True
[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($b)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

$a is not null as $a becomes a new string object with `read-host`.  Powershell won't let you create a null variable as `$null` is null.  To demonstrate that, type in `Set-Variable $a` in the console.  You'll return an error that basically tells you that you cannot bind the variable to null.

Your variable is actually an empty string object.  Test it this way:

```
If($a -eq $null){Write-Host "a equals null"}
If($a -eq ""){Write-Host "a is not null";$a|get-member;$a.GetType()}
```

That second line of code will generate a lot of output.  Specifically of interest are:

```
$a.GetType() | select Name, BaseType
```